# How to convert stored procedure to SQL Server Compact Edition query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a stored procedure that I need to convert to a standard query. Since I'm using SQL Server Compact, no stored procedures.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
declare @colu nvarchar (max) , @hour int
set @hour = DATEPART(HH, GETDATE() )
select @hour
select @colu = 

case when @hour=24
then '[12:00AM(00:00)]'  
enter code here
when @hour >12 and @hour <24
then '['+ convert(varchar,@hour-12) +':00PM('+ convert(nvarchar ,@hour) +':00)]'
when @hour=12
then '[12:00PM(12:00)]'
when @hour <12 and @hour >9
then '['+convert(nvarchar ,@hour) +':00AM('+ convert(nvarchar ,@hour) +':00)]'
else '['+convert(nvarchar ,@hour) +':00AM(0'+ convert(nvarchar ,@hour) +':00)]'
end

select @colu
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql= 'select ID,'''+ @colu + ''' as time from table'  -- add quote here
select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Like I say, I'm kind of stumped here. Any ideas?

Comment: 99% of that is just building the `@colu` string which you can do in your development language as it looks like a basic transform based on the current date?

Comment: It would be very helpful to tell us [what you are trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/), not just what technique you have decided to use. Especially since your `exec` will throw the result away and not do anything with it.

Comment: It's ok, I was able to make it work using C# Code to do the calculations of what time of day it is. I can post that code if it would be helpful to others.

Comment: If you found an answer, please post it below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer, plus get a shiny new SO badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I used to determine the time value and dynamically specify the column name:

```
            float basalrate = 0;
        DateTime HourVal = Convert.ToDateTime(PumpEditTime);
        if (HourVal == null)
        {
            HourVal = DateTime.Now;
        }
        int hourval = HourVal.Hour;
        int ampmhour = Convert.ToInt32(HourVal.ToString("hh"));
        string hourampm = string.Empty;

        if (hourval == Convert.ToInt32("24"))
        {
            hourampm = "[12:00AM(00:00)]";
        }
        else if ((hourval > 12) && (hourval < 24))
        {
            hourampm = "[" + ampmhour + ":00PM(" + hourval + ":00)]";
        }
        else if (hourval == 12)
        {
            hourampm = "[12:00PM(12:00)]";
        }
        else if ((hourval < 12) && (hourval > 9))
        {
            hourampm = "[" + ampmhour + ":00AM(" + hourval + ":00)]";
        }
        else
        {
            hourampm = "[" + ampmhour + ":00AM(0" + hourval + ":00)]";
        }
```