# Converting Stored Procedure into a query (SQL Server Compact)?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to convert the following stored procedure into a query, so that I can use it in SQL Server CE

```
USE TestResults
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsertNewTest
     (@DeviceSerialNumber nvarchar(50), 
      @DeviceType nvarchar(50), 
      @ElapsedTime int) 
AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO [TestResults].[dbo].[Tests]([Date], [Device], [DeviceType], [ExecutionTimeMs])
     OUTPUT INSERTED.TestId
     VALUES (GETDATE(), @DeviceSerialNumber, @DeviceType, @ElapsedTime) 
END
GO
```

From the above script, all I can understand is that it takes three input parameters

1. DeviceSerialNumber
2. DeviceType
3. ElapsedTime

but it'll update 5 columns in the table `Tests` including `Date` and `TestId`.

Since I can't use stored procedures in SQL Server CE, I've converted the above script into a string query,

```
string queryString = "INSERT INTO Tests ([Date], [Device], [DeviceType], [ExecutionTimeMs]) VALUES (@Date, @DeviceSerialNumber, @DeviceType, @ElapsedTime)"
```

Now how to include `OUTPUT INSERTED.TestId` into the string( `queryString` ) ?

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975289/how-to-convert-stored-procedure-to-sql-server-compact-edition-query), but it doesn't help my problem

Thanks!

Comment: You could use [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) instead.

Comment: Yeah, thats's already available but I'm looking to provide a solution in SQL CE.

Comment: You can probably use SELECT @@IDENTITY immediately after the INSERT to return the TestId, assuming this is an identity column?

Comment: Yes, you're right it's identity column.

Comment: SQL Server CE doesn't support the `OUTPUT` clause

Comment: Just use "SELECT @identity" is a subsequent query, but do NOT close the connection in between the two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [@@IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187342.aspx) to return the last inserted identity value:

```
string queryString = "INSERT INTO Tests " + 
                  "([Date], [Device], [DeviceType], [ExecutionTimeMs]) " +
                  "VALUES (@Date, @DeviceSerialNumber,@DeviceType, @ElapsedTime); " + 
                  "SELECT @@IDENTITY;"
```

When you execute your query, you need to set it up to return a single value using the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method:

```
var newIdentity;
// set up the queryString variable & command using the above
newIdentity = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

This assumes that the column `TestId` is an identity column.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @marc_s I wasn't sure if scope identity would work when it's not in a stored proc, but I'll update this based on your gold badges.

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` **definitely** works in a "normal" ad-hoc SQL statement - no problems at all ...

Comment: I was pretty sure that SCOPE_IDENTITY doesn't work with SQL CE but I am also pretty sure that @@IDENTITY does work.  I could be wrong...

Comment: Well it turns out I was correct, SCOPE_IDENTITY() definitely doesn't work with SQL Compact, so you might want to change your answer back...? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8afa446d-1c9d-4378-af02-88a2170b32f4/scopeidentity-sqlce-problem?forum=sqlce

Comment: One other thing to note, the article marc_s linked to mentions that triggers can cause @@IDENTITY to not work.  SQL Compact doesn't have triggers.  Another possible issue is that someone else updates the table at the same time.  SQL Compact doesn't allow multiple users.  :P

Comment: I agree with Richard, The SCOPE_IDENTITY() doesn't work with SQL Server Compact.

Answer (score 1):

Though I accepted Tanner's answer, but I ended up doing like this,

```
string queryString = "INSERT INTO Tests " + "([Date], [Device], [DeviceType], [ExecutionTimeMs]) " +
                     "VALUES (@Date, @DeviceSerialNumber,@DeviceType, @ElapsedTime)";
string queryString2 = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";

DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand ();
command.CommandText = queryString;

// Added Parameters here

command.ExecuteNonQuery ();

command.CommandText = queryString2;
object testId =  command.ExecuteScalar ();
```

So I had to split the query into two string & run `ExecuteNonQuery` with the first string and run `ExecuteScalar` with the second string.